# How Maven project downloads dependencies from Maven central?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, maven-central

Have a few Maven projects in our environment, and currently it is downloading the required dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml file from Maven central.

I was trying to figure out where the URL for Maven central is provided in pom file or project level, and unable to find out. I thought it could be in settings.xml, and found the below script:

```
  <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
       <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
       </releases>
       <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
       </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
```

Can someone provide inputs on the details of providing the Maven central URL in project/pom file level or where do we mention it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is defined by maven core, more accurate in [maven-model-builder](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) (so called super pom).

If you like to change that which means usually to redirect everything via an internal repository manager the way to go is via the user `settings.xml` see for details: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

The user settings is located in users home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`.

You should prevent to define repositories in `pom.xml` files, because it happens that the location of such repositories (repo managers) may change which would result in `pom.xml` which can not being built anymore after a time.

Comment: May I know where do we place super pom in a project ?

Comment: Simply you can't because it's part of Maven itself. Use the given suggestions...